# How to change database design in a deployed application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, deployment

**Situation**

I'm creating a C#/WPF 4 application using a SQL Compact Edition database as a backend with the Entity Framework and deploying with ClickOnce.

I'm fairly new to applications using databases, though I don't suspect I'll have much problem designing and building the original database. However, I'm worried that in the future I'll need to add or change some functionality which will require me to change the database design after the database is already deployed and the user has data in the database.

**Questions**

1. Is it even possible to push an updated database design out to users via a clickonce update in the same way it is for code changes?
2. If I did, how would the user's data be affected?
3. How is this sort of thing done in real situations? What are some best-practices?

I figure that in the worst case, I'd need to build some kind of "version" number into the database or program settings and create some routine to migrate the user's current version of the database to the new one.

I appreciate any insight into my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: vewy, vewy, carefuwy </elmerfudd>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some 'tricks' that are employed when designing databases to allow for design changes.

Firstly, many database designers create views to code against, rather than coding directly to the tables.  This allows tables to be altered (split or merged, etc) while only requiring that the views are updated. You may want to investigate [database refactoring](http://databaserefactoring.com/) techniques for this.

Secondly, you can indeed add versioning information to the database (commonly done as a 'version' table with a single field).  Updating the database can be done through code or through scripts.  One system I worked on would automatically check the database version and then progressively update the schema through versions in code until it matched the required version for the runtime.  This was quite an undertaking.

Comment: +1 I work on a system that checks database versions and then updates the schema through code (mixture of SQL data definition statements and code to manipulate the database structure, through ADO in our case). The only alternative I can think of is to extract the user's data from the old databases into a clean new database. That would also be a fairly large undertaking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SQL Server CE doesn't support views, but that trick might come in handy for others. =) I think I'm going to implement some system to recursively migrate user data version-by-version to the current version of the DB. That'll also make it easier for me to deal with the situation of restoring backups which might be of older versions. (However, I think I'll do my best to design the database so it doesn't _need_ upgrading much!)

Answer (score 2):

I think your "worst" case is actually a pretty good route to go in this situation.  Maintain a database version in the DB and have your application check and update the DB as necessary.  If you build your updater correctly, it should be able to maintain the user's data.  Depending on the update this might involve creating temporary tables to hold the existing data and repopulating new versions of the tables from them.  You might be able to [include a new SDF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e%28VS.80%29.aspx) with the new schema in place in the update process and simply transfer the data.  It might be slightly easier that way -- you could use file naming to differentiate versions and trigger the update code that way.

Comment: Yea, if I went with the 'worst case' I'd make a new empty SDF and transfer the user's data from the old to new, then rename the file or something similar to that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately version control and change management for databases is desperately, *desperately* far from what you can do with the rest of your code.

If you have an internal-only environment there are a number of tools which will help you (DBGhost, Red Gate has a newish app, some deployment management apps) but all of them are less than full solutions imho, but they are mostly good enough.

For client-shipped solutions you really don't have anything better than your worst case I'm afraid. Just try and design with flexibility in mind - see Dr.Herbie's answer.

This is not a solved problem basically.

Answer (score 2):

"Smart Client Deployment with ClickOnce" by Brian Noyes has an excellent chapter on this issue. (Chapter 5)
ISBN 978-0-32-119769-6

He suggests something like this:

```
if(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.IsFirstRun) {
    MigrateData();
}

private void MigrateData() {
    string previousDb = Path.Combine(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory, @".\pre\mydb.sdf");

    if(!File.Exists(previousDb))
        return;

    string oldConnString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\.pre\mydb.sdf";
    string newConnString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydb.sdf";

    //If you are using datasets perform any migration here, with the old and new table adapters.
    //Otherwise use an .sql data migration script.
    //Store the version of the database in the database, and check that in the beginning of your update script and GOTO the correct line in the SQL script.

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a useful book. I'll definitely check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I got that book. It has a section about my situation almost exactly. Thanks a lot for the book tip, it really taught me a lot about ClickOnce.

Comment: @Benny Jobigan, what about that - copy file from ".pre" to default (ie. to DataDirectory) and run only update scripts, eg. ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... What do you think about it?

Comment: @prostynick I think it's the only viable solution when using ClickOnce.

Comment: @Benny Jobigan Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to include a version number somewhere in the database. If you have a table with miscellaneous system data, throw it in there, or create a table with one record just to hold the DB version number. Then whenever the program starts up, check if the database version is less than the expected version. If so, execute the required SQL CREATE, ALTER, etc, commands to bring it up to speed. Have a script or function for each version change. So if you see the database is currently at version 6 and the code expects version 8, execute the 6 to 7 update and the 7 to 8 update.

Another method we used on one project I worked was to ship a schema-only, no data database with the code. Every time you installed a new version the installer would also install the latest copy of this new blank database. Then when the program started it up it would compare the user's current database schema with the new database schema, and determine what database changes were needed on the fly. Like, if in the "reference schema" table Foo had a column named Bar, and there was no column Bar in the user's current database, we would generate a "alter table Foo add Bar ..." and execute it. While writing the first draft of the program to do this was a fair amount of work, once we'd done it there was pretty much zero maintenance to keep the DB schema up to date. The conversion was just done on the fly.

Note that this scheme doesn't handle DB changes that require changing data values, like if you add a new column that must be initially populated by doing some computation on data from other tables or some such. But if you can generate new data from old data, that must mean that the new data is redundant and your database is not normalized. I don't think the situation ever came up for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an app in Android with an SQLite database adding a table. I changed the name of the database to include a version extension, like: theDataBaseV1, deleted the previous one and the app works fine.

I just changed the name of the database and the name in this line of code

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "busesBogotaV2.db";
```

in the DBManager when its going to open.

Does anybody knows if this trivial solution has any unintended consequences?

Comment: In Android, if you're using the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), it has a method you can override to help you migrate the db on upgrade and downgrade.

Comment: yes, I know but in my case I have no version in the database. I have 10'000 downloads with a plain simple db, how do I incorporate the version? if there is a app already deployed?